# Perdida de paquetes entre centos virtual y un servdor de backups

Tags: centos, server, ping

Estoy tratando de hacer ping entre mi centos virtual cuya IP es 192.168.99.30/24 y un servidor de backups cuya ip es 192.168.101.17/24.

Si bien hace ping,se tiene gran pérdida de paquetes. (Por ejemplo de 114 transmitidos, solo 8 fueron recibidos)

Alguna sugerencia. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Revisa el cableado, comprate un tester para cables del tipo que utilices (imagino que rj45). Y si no es el cableado entonces solo queda las tarjetas de red o si hay algun hub/switch entre medio. Ves descartando hasta que lo encuentres.  Por cierto, ¿te pasa lo mismo desde el host hacia el servidor de backups?

Comment: No me pasa lo mismo desde el host hasta el servidor de backups. En este último caso la conexión es normal sin pérdida de paquetes.

Comment: Entonces olvidate de mi primer comentario, no parece relacionado con el hardware (si es que comparten tarjeta de red con el host claro).  ¿Y desde el host hasta la maquina virtual? ¿Se pierden paquetes?

Comment: Desde el host a la máquina virtual no se pierden paquetes. Es algo extraño. Cuando hago el ping desde la terminal de virtualbox hay pérdida de paquetes, pero justo acabo de conectarme a mi máquina virtual mediante putty, y hay transferencia normal sin pérdida de paquetes. De modo que una solución podría ser probar a conectarse desde putty y así ver si el problema persiste.

Comment: Ejecuta los dos pings a la vez, a ver si ambos pierden paquetes o no simultaneamente.  Solo por probar... dejalos en marcha un buen rato (o no, como quieras) y luego los cortas y comparas para salir de dudas.

Comment: Muchas gracias masterguru.

Comment: De nada, suerte! :-)